# Save Image within box

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm not sure if this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find a response.

I'm new to OpenCV, and I'm working on image segmentation of digits.

After greying, blurring and thresholding the image, I find the image's contours and create rectangles using the code below.

```
import cv2
import imutils
from boxDetector import sort_contours
im = "/Users/vkhanna/Downloads/IMG_5667.jpg"


# im = "IMG_5549.jpg"

def digitFinder(im):
    image = cv2.imread(im)
    resized = imutils.resize(image, width=400)

    # Grey image and smooth over image noise using Gaussian blurring
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Threshold image to find clear boundaries
    threshold_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 2)

    # Find image contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Fetch bounding boxes for contours
    contours, boundingBoxes = sort_contours(contours, method="left-to-right")

    rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]

    num = 0
  
    for rect in rects:

        # Draw the rectangles
        cv2.rectangle(blurred, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # Make the rectangular region around the digit
        leng = int(rect[3]*1.1)
        pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
        pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
        roi = im_th[pt1:pt1 + leng, pt2:pt2 + leng]

        # Dilate the image
        try:
            roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))
            cv2.imshow("ROI: %s" % im, roi)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            # cv2.imwrite("roi" + str(num) + ".png", roi)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        
        num += 1

cv2.imshow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", blurred)
```

The "Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs" works well as can be seen here:

[image]

But if I try to save the ROIs in the loop above, I get the threshold version of the image that would confuse my neural network (trained on the MNIST dataset), as shown here:

[image]

How do I get the ROI on the first image shown above?

Comment: For "Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs" you are showing `blurred` but in the loop you are showing `roi`. It would helpful if you add the upper part of your code and the original image.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question now.